# Preview a hash before write a file to disk

Tags: powershell, hash, output, md5, preview

I wrote code to hash some files, separated by extension within a folder. At the end, a hash file is generated. Is there a way to preview a hash "#MP3_DIR_$hash.txt" before the file is written to disk? I raise the question, as a way to save reading and writing to disk and speed up the script.

```
$directory = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory).FullName
Foreach ($path in $directory) {
  If (!(Test-Path -Path "$path\#MP3_DIR_*.txt")) {
    $array = @()
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*.mp3" | Foreach {((Get-FileHash "$_" -Algorithm MD5).Hash)} | ForEach-Object { $array += "$_" }
  }
  If (!($array -eq $null)) {
    $array = $array | Where-Object {$_}
    $array = $array | Sort

    $hashfile = (Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -InputStream ([System.IO.MemoryStream]::New([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($array)))).Hash
    
    $array | Set-Content -LiteralPath "$path\#MP3_DIR_$hashfile.txt"
  }
}
```

The variable "$hashfile" not output the same hash of the file writed as "$path#MP3_DIR_$hashfile.txt". How to preview the hash of this file before write the file to disc?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean you want to see in the console what you are writing to disk? In that case, add `-PassThru` to the `Set-Content` call. Otherwise, this question is not clear to me..

Comment: I wanted to avoid a new hash of the file after writing to disk in order to rename it.